# GitLab not sending email notifications (smtp)

Tags: email, notifications, gitlab

I did set up GitLab with the official [CE AMI](https://about.gitlab.com/aws/) and used the SMTP configuration setup (with `AWS SES`) as described [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/smtp.html#amazon-ses). Sending a test mail works without problems. **What is not working is receiving mail on notifications** (like "new comment" or "merge request").

For example my notification setting is `watch`(= all notifications). Now I add a new comment and mention myself, everything works fine, my `TODO` counter (right top) increases but no email is sent. I checked the `sidekiq.log` file and it says ...

`2017-04-24_18:35:38.21211 2017-04-24T18:35:38.212Z 3800 TID-os4gzzujo NewNoteWorker JID-a1f08d6db7451695d6830a6a INFO: start
2017-04-24_18:35:38.29925 2017-04-24T18:35:38.299Z 3800 TID-os4gzzujo NewNoteWorker JID-a1f08d6db7451695d6830a6a INFO: done: 0.087 sec`

... but no email is sent. Using `grep 'mail' sidekiq.log` doesn't yield anything useful either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. The important part is the last sentence on the [Notifications](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/workflow/notifications.html) help.

> You won't receive notifications for Issues, Merge Requests or Milestones created by yourself. You will only receive automatic notifications when somebody else comments or adds changes to the ones that you've created or mentions you.

So when you're setting up GitLab on your own, create another dummy user, then impersonate that user and mention your actual account. That way you will receive an email notification.

Comment: Will root/admin receive notifications from another user?